# moving between section page using next and previous button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the same page I have multiple sections.

One `section` will be shown and this will happen using an `active` `class`.

In the same page I have `li` buttons 1, 2 and 3 and when I click on one of them the `section` related to it appears and the old one disappears. For that purpose I'm using Javascript.

Also in the same page I have a next and previous button. When I click on the next button the next `section` should appear and the old one should disappear.

And also the related `li` to the section should have the `active` `class`, the same thing for the previous: when I click on it it should go to the old `section` and the current should disappear and the `li` `class` should be `active`.

When I'm in the first `section` the  previous button should disappear and when I'm in the last section the next button should disappear.

How can I implement this behavior for the next and previous buttons in this way using Javascript?

Any Help Please!!?

```js
let tab = document.querySelector(".nav li");
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
let tabsArray = Array.from(tabs);
let section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
let sectionArray = Array.from(section);
let nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
let prevButton = document.querySelector(".previous");
let current = 0;

tabsArray.forEach((ele) => {
    ele.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        tabsArray.forEach((ele) => {
            ele.classList.remove("active");
        });
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
        
        sectionArray.forEach((sec) => {
            sec.classList.remove("active");
        });
        if(e.currentTarget.dataset.cont =='r1'){
           prevButton.classList.add("disable");
        }else{
          prevButton.classList.remove("disable");
  }
if (
  document.querySelector("#" + e.currentTarget.dataset.cont) ==
  sectionArray[sectionArray.length - 1]
) {
  nextButton.classList.add("disable");
} else {
  nextButton.classList.remove("disable");
}
        document.querySelector('#' + e.currentTarget.dataset.cont).classList.add("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.section {
display: none;
}

.section.active{
display: block;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

ul li {
background: #ccc;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin-left: 6px;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .5;
}

ul li.active{
opacity: 1 !important;
}

.next,
.previous {
padding: 15px 10px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: deepskyblue;
color: white;
border:0;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
}

.next.disable,
.previous.disable{
  cursor: none;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active" data-cont="r1">1</li>
<li data-cont="r2">2</li>
<li data-cont="r3">3</li>
</ul>


<section id="r1" class="section section-one active">
<h2>section 1</h2>
</section>
<section id="r2" class="section section-two">
<h2>section 2</h2>
</section>
<section id="r3" class="section section-three">
<h2>section 3</h2>
</section>


<button class="previous disable" id="previous">Previous</button>
<button class="next" id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: When clicking next button, you should get the current active form, when the current active form is 3, next button listener should not trigger, same to previous button when the current section is 1, it should be disabled. Add listener to your section form, or you can visit bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#tabs to have more info

Comment: @Forbidden can you please help me more in that and have an example how to do it

Comment: To clarify, if you start on `1` and click on `3`, should clicking the previous button take you back to `1` (because you were just on `1`)? Or should it take you to `2`, because that's the option before `3`

Comment: @NickParsons should take you back to 2 not to 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's advisable to have a collection of buttons and another for sections, connecting the two via the index, which needs to also be tracked. If we have all this, then going next is increasing the index, while going previous is decreasing the index. I'm not making previous and next disappear, even though the question asks me to do so. Instead I'm using the `disable` class. If we want to make them appear/disappear, then we can use the `invisible` `class` instead.

```js
let currentSection = 0;
let sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
let sectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".nav > li");
let nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
let previousButton = document.querySelector(".previous");
for (let i = 0; i < sectionButtons.length; i++) {
    sectionButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        sections[currentSection].classList.remove("active");
        sectionButtons[currentSection].classList.remove("active");
        sections[currentSection = i].classList.add("active");
        sectionButtons[currentSection].classList.add("active");
        if (i === 0) {
            if (previousButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") < 0) {
                previousButton.classList.add("disable");
            }
        } else {
            if (previousButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") >= 0) {
                previousButton.classList.remove("disable");
            }
        }
        if (i === sectionButtons.length - 1) {
            if (nextButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") < 0) {
                nextButton.classList.add("disable");
            }
        } else {
            if (nextButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") >= 0) {
                nextButton.classList.remove("disable");
            }
        }
    });
}

nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (currentSection < sectionButtons.length - 1) {
        sectionButtons[currentSection + 1].click();
    }
});

previousButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (currentSection > 0) {
        sectionButtons[currentSection - 1].click();
    }
});
```

```css
.section {
display: none;
}

.section.active{
display: block;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

ul li {
background: #ccc;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin-left: 6px;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .5;
}

ul li.active{
opacity: 1 !important;
}

.next,
.previous {
padding: 15px 10px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: deepskyblue;
color: white;
border:0;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
}

.next.disable,
.previous.disable{
  cursor: none;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active" data-cont="r1">1</li>
<li data-cont="r2">2</li>
<li data-cont="r3">3</li>
</ul>


<section id="r1" class="section section-one active">
<h2>section 1</h2>
</section>
<section id="r2" class="section section-two">
<h2>section 2</h2>
</section>
<section id="r3" class="section section-three">
<h2>section 3</h2>
</section>


<button class="previous disable" id="previous">Previous</button>
<button class="next" id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understand your question well and the solution below helps.

It is broken into small functions, the goal being that one function does one thing.

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
let sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
let nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
let prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
let current = 0;

const toggleTabs = () => {
  tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    tab.classList.remove('active');
  });
  tabs[current].classList.add("active");
  //console.log(current);
}

const toggleSections = () => {
  sections.forEach(function(section) {
    section.classList.remove('active');
  });
  sections[current].classList.add("active");
}

const togglePrev = () => {
  const method = current == 0 ? 'add' : 'remove';
  prevButton.classList[method]("disable");
}

const toggleNext = () => {
  const method = current == tabs.length - 1 ? 'add' : 'remove';
  nextButton.classList[method]("disable");
}

const goNext = () => {
  if (current < tabs.length - 1) {
    current++
  }
  toggleTabs();
  toggleSections();
  toggleNext();
  togglePrev();
}

const goPrev = () => {
  if (current > 0) {
    current--
  }
  toggleTabs();
  toggleSections();
  toggleNext();
  togglePrev();
}
```

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}

.section.active {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
}

ul li.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.next,
.previous {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.next.disable,
.previous.disable {
  cursor: none;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>


<section class="section section-one active">
  <h2>section 1</h2>
</section>
<section class="section section-two">
  <h2>section 2</h2>
</section>
<section class="section section-three">
  <h2>section 3</h2>
</section>


<button class="previous disable" id="prevBtn" onclick="goPrev()">Previous</button>
<button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="goNext()">Next</button>
```

Here is a **class-based solution** with some CSS changes to center the content:

```js
class TabbedContent {
  constructor() {
    this.tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
    this.sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
    this.nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
    this.prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
    this.current = 0;
  }

  toggleTabs() {
    this.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
      tab.classList.remove('active');
    });
    this.tabs[this.current].classList.add("active");
  }

  toggleSections() {
    this.sections.forEach(function(section) {
      section.classList.remove('active');
    });
    this.sections[this.current].classList.add("active");
  }

  togglePrev() {
    const method = this.current == 0 ? 'add' : 'remove';
    this.prevButton.classList[method]("disable");
  }

  toggleNext() {
    const method = this.current == this.tabs.length - 1 ? 'add' : 'remove';
    this.nextButton.classList[method]("disable");
  }

  goNext() {
    if (this.current < this.tabs.length - 1) {
      this.current++
    }
    this.toggleTabs();
    this.toggleSections();
    this.toggleNext();
    this.togglePrev();
  }

  goPrev() {
    if (this.current > 0) {
      this.current--
    }
    this.toggleTabs();
    this.toggleSections();
    this.toggleNext();
    this.togglePrev();
  }

}

const tabbedContent = new TabbedContent();
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.section {
  display: none;
}

.section.active {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
}

ul li.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.next,
.previous {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.next.disable,
.previous.disable {
  cursor: none;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>


  <section class="section section-one active">
    <h2>section 1</h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section section-two">
    <h2>section 2</h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section section-three">
    <h2>section 3</h2>
  </section>


  <button class="previous disable" id="prevBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goPrev()">Previous</button>
  <button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the "previous"/"next" button disappear without changing the layout, then you can set those buttons to "visibility:hidden;" by default in CSS and change it to "visibility:visible;" when the relevant event is triggered.

Also you can use the "button" tag instead of the "li" tag for the top navbar as well.

Below is my code:

```js
const sectionContent = ["r1", "r2", "r3"];
let currentSection = sectionContent[0];

const displayContent = (q, area) => {
    document.getElementById(q).classList.add("active");
    document.getElementById(q + "-button").classList.add("button-active");
    currentSection = sectionContent[area.indexOf(q)];
    const toNone = area.filter(e => e !== q);
    for (i in toNone) {
        document.getElementById(toNone[i]).classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById(toNone[i] + "-button").classList.remove("button-active");
    }
    if (sectionContent.indexOf(q) == 0) {
        document.getElementById("previous").classList.remove("button-active");
        document.getElementById("next").classList.add("button-active");
    }
    else if (sectionContent.indexOf(q) == sectionContent.length - 1) {
        document.getElementById("previous").classList.add("button-active");
        document.getElementById("next").classList.remove("button-active");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("previous").classList.add("button-active");
        document.getElementById("next").classList.add("button-active");
    }
}

const displayR1 = () => displayContent("r1", sectionContent);
const displayR2 = () => displayContent("r2", sectionContent);
const displayR3 = () => displayContent("r3", sectionContent);

const displayNext = () => displayContent(sectionContent[sectionContent.indexOf(currentSection) + 1], sectionContent);
const displayPrevious = () => displayContent(sectionContent[sectionContent.indexOf(currentSection) - 1], sectionContent);
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.section {
display: none;
}

.section.active {
display: block;
}

.nav {
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.nav button {
background: #ccc;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin-left: 6px;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .5;
border: none;
}

.next,
.previous {
padding: 15px 10px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: deepskyblue;
color: white;
border:0;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
visibility: hidden;
}

.button-active {
opacity: 1 !important;
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
            <button class="button-active" id="r1-button" onclick="displayR1()">1</button>
            <button id="r2-button" onclick="displayR2()">2</button>
            <button id="r3-button" onclick="displayR3()">3</button>
        </nav>

        <section id="r1" class="section active">
            <h2>section 1</h2>
        </section>
        <section id="r2" class="section">
            <h2>section 2</h2>
        </section>
        <section id="r3" class="section">
            <h2>section 3</h2>
        </section>

        <nav>
            <button class="previous" id="previous" onclick="displayPrevious()">Previous</button>
            <button class="next button-active" id="next" onclick="displayNext()">Next</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
tabsArray.forEach((ele) => {
    ele.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        tabsArray.forEach((ele) => {
            ele.classList.remove("active");
        });
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
        
        sectionArray.forEach((sec) => {
            sec.classList.remove("active");
        });
    // get the current click section
    // if the current section is 3
    // Then next button should be disabled
    // else if the current section is 1
    // Then prev button should be disabled


        document.querySelector('#' + e.currentTarget.dataset.cont).classList.add("active");
    });
});
```

Sorry not good at plain Javascript,
But for easy visualization
That should be the process

You may identify the current section by getting the `data-cont` attribute,
Using jQuery the code will be
`$(ele).attr('data-cont')` which will return any `r1`, `r2`, or `r3`

```js
// Get the current data-cont value in li attribute
var currSection = $(ele).attr('data-cont')
// Disable previous button when currSection is r1
$('button.previous').prop('disabled', currSection == 'r1')
// Disable next button when currSection is r3
$('button.next').prop('disabled', currSection == 'r3')
```

Comment: i edit my code for the previous button how to make it for the next button page can contain more than 3 or less than 3 it's dynamic not static

Comment: In that case, you have to identify the first and last element identification,
You can select all the `li`'s and get the first and last element, in that way, you will get the `data-cont`.

Comment: Example:
for first eleemnt `$('li').get(0)`
for the last element `$('li').get($('li').length-1)`

Then store those resulting element
`var firstList = $('li').get(0)`
`var lastList = $('li').get($('li').length-1)`

Not a good code, but for demo purposes
Then you can now compare the current active `li` to the first and last li to determine, and to toggle next and previous buttons disabled state

Comment: i update my code for the previous and next button but now when i click on the next or previous button how should be done?

Comment: First, when clicking next you have to find the current element, then get the next element of it,
Just remove the `.active` class on the current element and add `.active` class on the next element

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sectionContent = ["r1", "r2", "r3"];
let currentSection = sectionContent[0];

const displayContent = (q, area) => {
    document.getElementById(q).classList.add("active");
    document.getElementById(q + "-button").classList.add("button-active");
    currentSection = sectionContent[area.indexOf(q)];
    const toNone = area.filter(e => e !== q);
    for (i in toNone) {
        document.getElementById(toNone[i]).classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById(toNone[i] + "-button").classList.remove("button-active");
    }
    if (sectionContent.indexOf(q) == 0) {
        document.getElementById("previous").classList.remove("button-active");
        document.getElementById("next").classList.add("button-active");
    }
    else if (sectionContent.indexOf(q) == sectionContent.length - 1) {
        document.getElementById("previous").classList.add("button-active");
        document.getElementById("next").classList.remove("button-active");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("previous").classList.add("button-active");
        document.getElementById("next").classList.add("button-active");
    }
}

const displayR1 = () => displayContent("r1", sectionContent);
const displayR2 = () => displayContent("r2", sectionContent);
const displayR3 = () => displayContent("r3", sectionContent);

const displayNext = () => displayContent(sectionContent[sectionContent.indexOf(currentSection) + 1], sectionContent);
const displayPrevious = () => displayContent(sectionContent[sectionContent.indexOf(currentSection) - 1], sectionContent);
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.section {
display: none;
}

.section.active {
display: block;
}

.nav {
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.nav button {
background: #ccc;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin-left: 6px;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .5;
border: none;
}

.next,
.previous {
padding: 15px 10px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: deepskyblue;
color: white;
border:0;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
visibility: hidden;
}

.button-active {
opacity: 1 !important;
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
            <button class="button-active" id="r1-button" onclick="displayR1()">1</button>
            <button id="r2-button" onclick="displayR2()">2</button>
            <button id="r3-button" onclick="displayR3()">3</button>
        </nav>

        <section id="r1" class="section active">
            <h2>section 1</h2>
        </section>
        <section id="r2" class="section">
            <h2>section 2</h2>
        </section>
        <section id="r3" class="section">
            <h2>section 3</h2>
        </section>

        <nav>
            <button class="previous" id="previous" onclick="displayPrevious()">Previous</button>
            <button class="next button-active" id="next" onclick="displayNext()">Next</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.